# Why is Julia allocating so much memory?

Tags: performance, memory, optimization, garbage-collection, julia

I am trying to write a fast coordinate descent algorithm for solving ordinary least squares regression.  The following Julia code works, but I don't understand why it's allocating so much memory

```
function OLS_cd{T<:Float64}(A::Array{T,2}, b::Array{T,1}, tolerance::T=1e-12) 
    N,P = size(A)
    x = zeros(P)
    r = copy(b)
    d = ones(P)
    while sum(d.*d) > tolerance
        @inbounds for j = 1:P
            d[j] = sum(A[:,j].*r)
            x[j] += d[j]
            r -= d[j]*A[:,j]
        end
    end
    return(x)
end
```

On the data I generate with

```
n = 100
p = 75
σ = 0.1
β_nz = float([i*(-1)^i for i in 1:10])

β = append!(β_nz,zeros(p-length(β_nz)))
X = randn(n,p); X .-= mean(X,1); X ./= sqrt(sum(abs2(X),1))
y = X*β + σ*randn(n); y .-= mean(y);
```

Using `@benchmark OLS_cd(X, y)` I get

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  65.94 mb
  allocs estimate:  151359
  --------------
  minimum time:     19.316 ms (16.49% GC)
  median time:      20.545 ms (16.60% GC)
  mean time:        22.164 ms (16.24% GC)
  maximum time:     42.114 ms (10.82% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          226
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
```

The OLS problem gets harder as `p` gets bigger, and I've noticed that the as I make p bigger and need to run longer, the more memory Julia allocates.

Why would each pass through the `while` loop allocate more memory?  To my eye, it seems like all of my operations are in place, and the types are clearly specified.

Nothing popped out to me while profiling, but I could post that output as well if it's useful.

**Update:**
As pointed out below, temporary arrays caused by using vectorized operations were the culprit.  The following eliminated extraneous allocations and runs pretty quickly:

```
function OLS_cd_unrolled{T<:Float64}(A::Array{T,2}, b::Array{T,1}, tolerance::T=1e-12) 
    N,P = size(A)
    x = zeros(P)
    r = copy(b)
    d = ones(P)    
    while norm(d,Inf) > tolerance
        @inbounds for j = 1:P
            d[j] = 0.0; @inbounds for i = 1:N d[j] += A[i,j]*r[i] end
            @inbounds for i = 1:N r[i] -= d[j]*A[i,j] end
            x[j] += d[j]
        end
    end
    return(x)
end
```

Comment: Minor point, why use parameterization, when you then say that it must be a Float64?  Wouldn't it be more powerful to just have it be T<:Real? Also, the zeros(P) and ones(P) won't pick up the correct type, they should be zeros(T, P) and ones(T,P), and in the inner loop, d[j] = zero(T).

Comment: That's a good point.  I'm still pretty rough with the type specification stuff in Julia.

Comment: Also, why access d[j] from the array, and why two loops? Why not: `dj = zero(T) ; @inbounds for i = 1:N ; aij = A[i,j] ; dj += aij*r[i] ; r[i] -= dj*aij ; end ; x[j] += dj ; d[j] = dj` (I am not a mathematician, so maybe I'm all wet here!)

Comment: You're right that dj could just be a scalar, but keeping the array of differences (whence d) makes testing for convergence cleaner, and copying between a scalar and the array doesn't seem like it would speed things up over just accessing the array.  Regarding the two loops, I did try to put them in the same loop, but it changed the output significantly.  I'm not sure why -- I don't think it should.

Comment: For what it's worth, the above code is already faster than the built-in `X\y` for most values of `n` and `p` that I've tested on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A[:,j]` creates a copy, not a view. You want to use `@view A[:,j]` or `view(A,:,j)`.

You can devectorize `r -= d[j]*A[:,j]` with `r .= -.(r,d[j]*A[:.j])` to get rid of some more temporaries. As @LutfullahTomak said `sum(A[:,j].*r)` should devectorize as `dot(view(A,:,j),r)` to get rid of all of the temporaries in there. To use  an infix operator, you can use `\cdot`, as in `view(A,:,j)⋅r`.

You should read up on copies vs views and how vectorization causes temporary arrays. The jist of it is that when vectorized operations occur, they have to create a new vector as output. Instead, you want to write to an existing vector. `r = ...` for an array changes reference, so `r = ex` for some expression which makes an array will make a new array, and then point `r` to that array. `r .= ex` will replace the values of the array `r` with the values from the expression. The former allocates a temporary, the latter does not. Repeated applications of this idea is where all of the temporaries come from.

Comment: I thought `.=` is for 0.6 but it works in 0.5 to my surprise. I did `r .= (-).(r,(*).(d[j],view(A,:,5)))`. I think it should be `(-).(...)` for `broadcast(-,...)`

Comment: I don't think the parenthesis are necessary. But as an FYI for the thread, `.` fusion for `.+` and all of that is merging on Monday. [This is the issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/17623#issuecomment-267784596), so it'll be on the nightlies in a few days (but if you're not very experienced with Julia, I would not advise using it)

Comment: I couldn't get the view approach to work, but unrolling the vectorized assignment into for loops seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I get this error if I remove parenthesis around `-` , `ERROR: syntax: numeric constant "-." cannot be implicitly multiplied because it ends with "."` Also, I made a typo before it should be `r .= (-).(r,(*).(d[j],view(A,:,j)))`

Comment: Yeah, Julia Version 0.5.0 Commit 3c9d753 (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC).  The sum -> dot worksed nicely, but the view stuff didn't seem to work.  I might look into it again if the code becomes too overwhelmed by unrolled loops.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `sum(d.*d)` , `sum(A[:,j].*r)` and so on are not inplace and make temporary arrays.. First, `sum(d.*d) == dot(d,d)` I think and `sum(A[:,j].*r)` makes 2 temporary arrays. I'd do `dot(view(A,:,j),r)` for the latter. Current stable version of julia(0.5) doesn't have short version for `r -= d[j]*A[:,j]` so you need to devectorize it make a loop.